# phpmyadmin: Disable export privileges for a table

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

We want to be able to prevent the exporting of certain tables within phpMyAdmin - just in case one of our tech's accidentally tries to export one of the tables that will freeze the database. Is this possible without rewriting phpMyAdmin!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by creating different users with different privileges. This wont freeze the database but still wont let him do it.

Comment: Fair comment... however they are all developers and have access to the root mysql - so actually a stupid question on my part! Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't have any better ideas.
Anyway, if i helped somehow you could accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of a user permission that prevents exporting a database. Are you talking about MySQL privileges here?

Answer (score 0):

Using the relatively new feature of [user groups](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_usergroups), you can hide the Export tabs. This applies on a per-user basis and is global; you can't only hide it for particular databases or table names. It's not ideal based on what you've described, but I think it's the closest you'll get from within phpMyAdmin (without making changes to the code yourself).